# How do I create a filter function javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, filter

Does someone know how to write this code?
On clicking the button, create a new table from people table, which will only contain people whose age is greater than 18 . Display the resulting array in the console

```
 const people = [
        {
            firstname: "Dreddy",
            lastname: "Nussgen",
            age: 70,
        },
        {
            firstname: "Yves",
            lastname: "Sear",
            age: 49,
        },
        {
            firstname: "Marcel",
            lastname: "Cowderay",
            age: 59,
        },
        {
            firstname: "Dag",
            lastname: "Binnall",
            age: 31,
        },
        {
            firstname: "Horten",
            lastname: "Claesens",
            age: 75,
        },
        {
            firstname: "Charmian",
            lastname: "Harnes",
            age: 10,
        },
        {
            firstname: "Sean",
            lastname: "Littlejohns",
            age: 37,
        },
        {
            firstname: "Hazlett",
            lastname: "Sprouls",
            age: 87,
        },
        {
            firstname: "Marcel",
            lastname: "Hasted",
            age: 66,
        },
        {
            firstname: "Cary",
            lastname: "Summerson",
            age: 15,
        },
        {
            firstname: "Feodor",
            lastname: "Ollett",
            age: 56,
        },
        {
            firstname: "Kelly",
            lastname: "Ranahan",
            age: 62,
        },
        {
            firstname: "Madelene",
            lastname: "Davie",
            age: 14,
        },
        {
            firstname: "Bent",
            lastname: "Karpe",
            age: 82,
        },
        {
            firstname: "Reinaldo",
            lastname: "Grimbleby",
            age: 81,
        },
    ];
```

Comment: You can use `Array.prototype.filter()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Code:

```js
const people = [{firstname: 'Dreddy',lastname: 'Nussgen',age: 70,},{firstname: 'Yves',lastname: 'Sear',age: 49,},{firstname: 'Marcel',lastname: 'Cowderay',age: 59,},{firstname: 'Dag',lastname: 'Binnall',age: 31,},{firstname: 'Horten',lastname: 'Claesens',age: 75,},{firstname: 'Charmian',lastname: 'Harnes',age: 10,},{firstname: 'Sean',lastname: 'Littlejohns',age: 37,},{firstname: 'Hazlett',lastname: 'Sprouls',age: 87,},{firstname: 'Marcel',lastname: 'Hasted',age: 66,},{firstname: 'Cary',lastname: 'Summerson',age: 15,},{firstname: 'Feodor',lastname: 'Ollett',age: 56,},{firstname: 'Kelly',lastname: 'Ranahan',age: 62,},{firstname: 'Madelene',lastname: 'Davie',age: 14,},{firstname: 'Bent',lastname: 'Karpe',age: 82,},{firstname: 'Reinaldo',lastname: 'Grimbleby',age: 81,},]

const result = people.filter(({ age }) => age > 18)

console.log(result)
```